# Python's requests triggers Cloudflare

Tags: python, python-requests, cloudflare, httpx

```
import requests , json
from collections import OrderedDict
def Core(): 
            response = requests.Session()
            headers = OrderedDict({'Authorization': 'bearer 0',    
                    'BrandType': '1',                            
                    'AppBrand': '1',
                    'Accept-Language': 'en-US',                    
                    'X-Device-Source': '6',
                    'X-Device-Version': '9.99',                     
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',    
                    'User-Agent': 'Dalvik/2.1.0 (11)',
                    'Host': 'api.talabat.com',                  
                    'Connection': 'close'})
            url = 'https://api.talabat.com/apiAndroid/v2/customer/verifyoption'
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            print(response.status_code)
            print(response.text)                 

Core()
```

Problem : Gives response code 403

I have tried the above request within burpsuite with same ip address , same headers and it working fine . But i can't pass within python requests or httpx

Comment: It's not surprising that an automated request would trigger a system to block automated requests.

Comment: I have used burpsuite and it working fine with him

Answer (score -1):

Have you try cloudscraper?

```py
import cloudscraper as cs

scraper = cs.create_scraper()
result = scraper.get("http://www.example.com")
print(result)
```

Comment: Yes same problem .. i can pass this request in any application expect python